# Checkbox click event fires before change event in Firefox unlike in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox, dom-events

I have two events for a check-box in my script one on click and another on change.
When I click on it it fires change event first then click event in Chrome but in Firefox it's reverse. Is there any way to change the order of it in Firefox?

Comment: Can you share your code? Why do you have two events?

Comment: @LinkinTED Thats because i have a dropdown control which is dependent on check-box click.if you dont select any item from dropdown then user should not be able to check the check-box.in the mean time i need to show message based on check-box check and uncheck.

Comment: Could you share your code? I don't see why you can't put everything in to a single change handler. I believe IE behaves the same as Firefox (click fires first - which makes sense to me, as you need to click in order to change)

Comment: How about using only the change event. In that function you first check if a value is set. When not, return false, else execute the function...? Please add your functions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the order in which the events are fired is inconsistent between browsers, but I don't see why you can't move everything in to a single `change` handler. If you must use separate handlers, you could add a timeout, the click event would still fire first in Firefox, but its code wouldn't be executed until after the change handler fires.

```
var myBoolean = false;

$('#example').on({
    'click': function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('clicked'); 
            console.log(myBoolean);
        }, 1);
    },
    'change': function() {
        console.log('changed');
        myBoolean = true;
    }
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfh5jhb6/3/)

Comment: IT WORK, THANK YOU