# Why was the .on('click', function(){}) seemingly executing the function without any actual clicks occuring after handler got attached?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am trying to make a selection box where if you click on the active selection, it will deselect everything. But it seems like the change event of the select box is firing before the click event of the option. That causes event handler attachments added during the change event firing to be triggered without any clicks actually occuring after the event handler was attached. What would be the best way to get around this problem?

[checkbox click event fires before change event in firefox unlike in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604630/checkbox-click-event-fires-before-change-event-in-firefox-unlike-in-chrome)
this offered setTimeout as a way to get around it. But in this case here, I can't do that because I don't want the change event to fire at all. Or if there is a way to mute the click event from that first change event, that will be fine too, but I don't think there is a way to do that, or is there?

I have been trying it on a fiddle. I have created

1. *A checkbox to illustrate the concept of what I am trying to achieve.*
2. *A selection box with only one option using the same code to illustrate the issue*
3. *An more elaborate example with more than one option that I am ultimately wanting to do*

The event handler I used to attach the handler is shown below. For full code, see fiddle.

```
$(jqID+" option:selected").on("click", function(){
         deSelect($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```js
// Checkbox test code that starts with change when first check was made, and subsequent showing click bloc code only on second click -> that is the expected behavior
$("#checkbox").on('change', function() {
  console.log("changed");

  $("#checkbox").on('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    $("#checkbox").off('click');
    console.log("click evthandler off");
  });
  console.log("click evthandler on");
});

// Select code with exact same set up
$("#selectbox").on('change', function() {
  console.log("selbox changed");

  $("#SO1").on('click', function() {
    console.log("selopt clicked");
    $("#SO1").prop("selected", false); //Added this line to deselect option
    $("#SO1").off('click');
    console.log("selopt click evthandler off");
  });
  console.log("selopt click evthandler on");
});

// Select box code: ______________________________________
// Attach the original change event handler like the above
$("#S1").on("change", function() {
  toggleSelected("S1")
});

// toggleSelected baseically turns off all option level click event handlers, and then it adds it back on for only the actively selected option currently.
function toggleSelected(jsID) {
  var jqID = "#" + jsID;
  var selElements = $(jqID + " option:selected");
  var allTargets = $(jqID);

  console.log("toggleSelected Executed");

  // Cleans out all event handlers on the options
  allTargets.children("option").off("click");

  // Attaches event handler for active option
  if (typeof selElements !== "undefined" && selElements.length == 0) {
    console.log("no elements selected or error reading selection set");
  } else {
    console.log("before attaching event handler for clicks");
    $(jqID + " option:selected").on("click", function() {
      console.log("within click function before deSelect");
      deSelect($(this).attr('id'));
      console.log("within click function after deSelect");
    });
    console.log("after attaching event handler for clicks");
  }
}

// deSelect is deselects the option. Test functions have been removed for ease of reading
function deSelect(jsID) {
  console.log("deSelect Executed");

  $("#" + jsID).prop("selected", false); //This deselects the option

  console.log("deSelect refresh calling of toggleSelected");
  toggleSelected("S1"); //I just did S1 for the sake of simplicity here.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">

<select id="selectbox" class="catSelect" title="Taa" size="4">
  <option id="SO1" value="1" class="catOptions">Laa</option>
</select>

<select id="S1" class="catSelect" title="Taa" size="4">
  <option id="SO1" value="1" class="catOptions">Laa</option>
  <option id="SO2" value="2" class="catOptions">Paa</option>
  <option id="SO3" value="3" class="catOptions">Waa</option>
  <option id="SO4" value="4" class="catOptions">Maa</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silveryne/koLwvfye/44/#&togetherjs=j13PlzvnhS)

As you can see, the checkbox worked as expected. On the first click, it only showed:

- *changed*
- *click evthandler on*

and does not include

- *clicked*
- *click evthandler off*

When a selection was picked on the selection box, the console log is shown as follows:

- *selbox changed*
- *selopt click evthandler on*
- *selopt clicked*
- *selopt click evthandler off*

which clearly shows that the click did trigger, but it was actually after the change handler completed its job.

How can I make is so that the outcome of when an option is selected is:

- *selbox changed*
- *selopt click evthandler on*

---

The third selection box is essentially the same, but with more options for testing. It might be helpful but you can skip it if you only need to understand the issue I am having. But the desired behavior of the third box would be:

- *toggleSelected Executed*
- *before attaching event handler for clicks*

and the rest should be shown only when the selected option was clicked on subsequently:

- *within click function before deSelect*
- *deSelect Executed*
- *deSelect refresh calling of toggleSelected*
- *toggleSelected Executed*
- *no elements selected or error reading selection set*
- *within click function after deSelect*

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add event handlers inside other event handlers.

Comment: What is `type="text"` supposed to mean in `<select>`? That attribute is only meaningful in `<input>`

Comment: I removed it - it wouldn't make a difference.